# Import unqualified name in Node.js

Tags: node.js, require, qualified-name

In Python I can import the names in my module as qualified

```
import myModule
```

or unqualified

```
from myModule import *
```

In Node.js, I can import as qualified

```
var myModule = require('myModule')
```

Is there a way to import names unqualified?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

ES6 imports are not supported in node.js at this point though. You could get it by writing ES6 code and transpiling it with babel, for example https://babeljs.io/